# How to count total number of rows and columns in a webtable using the selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

HTML:

```
<div class="attach">
<app-table>
<table class="table"> // 
<thead>
<tr>
<th><span>Name</span></th>
<th><span>Address</span></th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

<tr>
<td>aaa</td>
<td>bbb</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>aaa111</td>
<td>bbb222</td>
</tr>

</tr>

</tbody>

</table>
</app-table>
</div>
```

The page may have multiple web tables. However, parent element "attach" is unique for this table.
How can I count the total number of rows and columns? I found lot of info online but I could not fix it.

Comment: Just find the table and then use that element to xpath tr and td.

Answer (score 1):

from [www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-count-the-number-of-rows-in-a-table-in-selenium-with-python](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-count-the-number-of-rows-in-a-table-in-selenium-with-python):

```
# identifying the number of rows having <tr> tag
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr")
# len method is used to get the size of that list
print(len(rows))
#to close the browser
driver.close()
```

Number of cells may vary per row. But you can use xpath to count those too:

```
row1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr")
cols = row1.find_elements_by_xpath("//td")
print(len(cols))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have include the class name in the xpath to make it unique in your case.

```
#Number of columns in the table

cols = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class="attach"]//table/thead//th")
print(cols)

#Number of rows in the table

rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class="attach"]//table/tbody//tr")
print(rows )
```

Answer (score 0):

We can resolve this in Java Language as follows:

List rows=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class="attach"]//tbody//tr"));

int rowCount=rows.size();

List columns=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class="attach"]//table//th"));

int columnCount=columns.size();